# How to add X-XSS Protection to folders?

Tags: html, .htaccess, security, xss

I'm adding extra X-XSS Protection to my websites by adding this snippet to the .htaccess

```
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
    Header set X-XSS-Protection "1; mode=block"
    Header always append X-Frame-Options SAMEORIGIN
    Header set X-Content-Type-Options nosniff
</IfModule>
```

And it is working, but when I test the website using OWASP ZAP, it still shows warnings about disabled X-XSS on all the folders present inside the root, like:

```
https://mywebsite.com/folder/

https://mywebsite.com/images/
```

etc..

Basically on the folders there are no headers, which is understandable, but is there a way I can fix this to prevent OWASP showing the warnings?

**EDIT:** I found an easy solution. Basically I just created a custom 403 page and wrote a htaccess rule to redirect 403 responses to that page. This way the custom page will have the custom HTTP Headers.

Comment: If your folders are not readable, there is no problem. Zap based on the reading of the header.

Comment: @SPoint The access to the folders is restricted, it gives 403 to ZAP, but it still shows in the warnings. Should I just take it for false positive?

Comment: yes this is False Positive in this cases

Comment: Yea, I thought so, I managed to delete the warnings anyway, by creating a custom 403 page.